# Read .txt file to json data jquery-javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, text-files

I have code to auto generate .txt file, like that:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
string prdcontent = DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(dt);//this will generate json string
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/ContentPage/prdbank.txt"), prdcontent, Encoding.UTF8);
```

OK. I have a .txt file with this content:

> [{"matin":"1","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P - DT01P/08 - DT01P/16","cloaisp":"0"},{"matin":"12","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03P","cloaisp":"0"},{"matin":"17","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P60-RF","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"18","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03P05","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"19","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03P-RF","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"9","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P80-RF - mẫu 2","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"10","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03P-RF - mẫu 2","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"4","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P80-RF","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"5","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P60-RF - mẫu 2","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"22","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P-RF","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"23","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P-RF mẫu 2","cloaisp":"1"},{"matin":"28","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01P80-RF mô-đun RF gắn ngoài","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"26","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01M10","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"27","matl":"11","tieude":"1 pha DT01M80","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"16","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03M01","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"20","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03M10","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"14","matl":"11","tieude":"3 pha DT03M05","cloaisp":"3"},{"matin":"15","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ thu thập dữ liệu DCU","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"13","matl":"11","tieude":"Modem RMR TurboJet","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"21","matl":"11","tieude":"Hệ thống RFSPIDER","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"6","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ định tuyến dữ liệu Router","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"7","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ chuyển đổi RS232 / RS485","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"8","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ đọc chỉ số công tơ qua sóng vô tuyến RF-EXT","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"11","matl":"11","tieude":"Hệ thống Giám sát HEMS","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"2","matl":"11","tieude":"Thiết bị Handheld Unit","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"3","matl":"11","tieude":"Hệ thống thu thập và quản lý dữ liệu đo đếm MDMS","cloaisp":"2"},{"matin":"25","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ hiển thị chỉ số In Home display","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"29","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ mở rộng ELSTER-RF","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"31","matl":"11","tieude":"T.bị giám sát chất lượng lưới điện","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"36","matl":"11","tieude":"Bộ mở rộng chức năng RF cho công tơ Landis","cloaisp":""},{"matin":"37","matl":"11","tieude":"Thiết bị cảnh báo sự cố trên lưới trung thế","cloaisp":""}]

Now, I wanna read this txt file and use result as json data, I'm using this function:

```
var jsontext_prdbank = (readTextFile('../ContentPage/prdbank.txt'));
var jsontext = JSON.parse(jsontext_prdbank);
```

With readtextfile function:

```
function readTextFile(file) {
var rawtext;
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            var allText = JSON.stringify(rawFile.responseText);
            rawtext = allText;
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
return rawtext;
}
```

I get jsontext  like this: "[{"matin":"1.... (json string content)... cloaisp":""}]" but when I use
`for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = jsontext[i];}`

, row just is "[". So that's mean JSON.parse(jsontext_prdbank) just return a string, not a json data. How can I get json data to use in this case?

Comment: It's an object. Try to use `for(i in jsontext) { row = jsontext[i] }`.

Comment: I used for(i in jsontext) { row = jsontext[i] } like your comment and I still get jsontext[0] is: "["

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should be `JSON.parse`

Comment: @Đồng Vọng See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've used the following code in your function:

```
var allText = JSON.stringify(rawFile.responseText);
rawtext = allText;
```

Just use the following instead:

```
// rawFile.responseText is already in string form
// so parse it into an object and assign it to allText
var allText = JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);
```

Then you can use something like the following:

```
// jsontext_prdbank will get a parsed object, no need to parse it again
var jsontext_prdbank = (readTextFile('../ContentPage/prdbank.txt'));
```

Comment: Thanks ALpha. Hmmm ... I think my string has some problem (my .txt is longer my example), so when I use JSON.parse, I get this error: "Unexpected token in JSON at position ***". But if use JSON.stringify, I cannot get json array. >"< . So headache >"< .

Comment: Validate your json content using any online json validator.

Comment: You can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to validate your json, just copy the content from your text file and paste it there and process.

Comment: Thanks Alpha so much. I re-correct my json string and problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `JSON.stringify` from your original code, `responseText` is a string

```
var jsontext_prdbank = (readTextFile('../ContentPage/prdbank.txt'));
var jsontext = JSON.parse(jsontext_prdbank);

function readTextFile(file) {
var rawtext;
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            rawtext = rawFile.responseText;
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
return rawtext;
}
```

To loop through the object from `JSON.parse`

```
    for(i in jsontext) { row = jsontext[i] }
```

Comment: That's my mistake. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `JSON.stringify`, use `JSON.parse` to parse your file content to JavaScript object.